# Implementing custom workflow to Java issue tracking system

Tags: java, workflow, tracking

I am now programming a New Java issue tracking system. It will be JavaFx 8 + Spring 4 JDBC. I would like implement a feature where the Project Manager can create a custom workflow. Because every Company has their own issue controlling life cycle. Do you have any idea how should I start with this feature? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this as a configurable state machine. The states are the states of the tickets. the transitions are the allowed ways a ticket can change state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of open source workflow engines out there that you could just embed in your application:
http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

If you want to design it from scratch, take a look at common implementations of [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) and [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The hardest part will be the persistence as you'll have to save both the nodes and the arcs.